# Take user input as an operator into an expression

Tags: c, parsing, input, expression

Would it be possible to take a users input as a variable to be used in an expresion?

```
scanf("%s", op); //User enters "==" or "!="

if(x op y)
   //Go.
```

Comment: I've edited the to reflect the fact that c does not feature a operator keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The best you can do is something like:

```
scanf("%s", &op);
if (strcmp(op, "==") == 0) {
    result = x == y;
}
else if (strcmp(op, "!=") == 0) {
    result = x != y;
}

// now use result
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are essentially asking for is an ability to do eval. Some dynamic languages (python etc.) support it but not C. Even if eval is supported, you still need to do the input validation for security reason.

Following C code does this with an abstraction and a dispatch table :

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int (*func)(int op1, int op2);
struct op {
  char *opstr;
  func op_func;
};

int add_func(int op1, int op2)
{
  return op1 + op2;
}

int sub_func(int op1, int op2)
{
  return op1 - op2;
}

struct op ops[] = { {"+", add_func}, {"-", sub_func} };

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
  int x = 10, y = 5, i = 0;
  char op[10];
  scanf("%s", &op);
  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(ops)/sizeof(ops[0]); i++){
    if(strcmp(ops[i].opstr, op) == 0){
      printf("%d\n", ops[i].op_func(x, y));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```